# How to access newly added Contact in Sync Adapter onPerformSync method?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

When I add a contact to my phone book, the sync Adapter onPerformSync() method gets triggered. But I am not able to figure out how to retrieve the newly added Contact details within that method. Please help me with some guidance and code snippets. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contacts of your account are stored in the [`RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) table. The data (e.g. phone numbers, email addresses) is stored in the [Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.html) table (with `RAW_CONTACT_ID` pointing to the row `_ID` of that contact in the `RawContacts` table).

To detect new contacts, your sync adapter needs to maintain the `SOURCE_ID` field in the [`RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) table.

The documentation says about `SOURCE_ID` (in the columns of fields on top):

> String that uniquely identifies this row to its source account. Typically it is set at the time the raw contact is inserted and never changed afterwards. **The one notable exception is a *new* raw contact: it will have an account name and type (and possibly a data set), but no source id**. This indicates to the sync adapter that a new contact needs to be created server-side and its ID stored in the corresponding SOURCE_ID field on the phone.

So your sync adapter should look for contacts that belong to your account type and have an empty `SOURCE_ID`. After the contact has been synced it must set the `SOURCE_ID` to a (non-empty) value that identifies the new contact.

When you sync a new contact from the server you need to set the `SOURCE_ID` when inserting the new contact on Android. Failure to do so, will result in duplicates (since the contact would be synced back to the server as a new contact on the next sync).

Comment: @Marten Apart from Gmail contacts, other account types (e.g. Exchange) do not always seem to follow the rule of [SOURCE_ID being Stable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#ContactsProviderMetadata). Have you encountered or found a solution to anything similar?

Comment: @zafeiris.m sorry, we don't have use cases for reading `SOURCE_ID`s of other accounts. So we've never encountered this issue.

Comment: Its an old question, but I am trying to understand the Contacts thing. As said in the OP, if a new contact is added from the phone-book, it will be added into the RawContacts with `my_account_type`. `my_account_type` can only be added by `my_app` and for that I will have to know the only the new contacts, which again brings us back to the main question. Am i missing anything ?

Comment: @ZeekHuge you know that a contact is new if `SOURCE_ID` is `null` because it's your own responsibility to set it to something non-`null` after you've synced the contact. No other app will set `SOURCE_ID`.

Comment: @Marten : the `SOURCE_ID` inside the raw contact with `Account name` = `my_account`. right ? And that raw contact is added by `my app`. But If I dont know what new contact was added, how would I add that contact to the raw contacts of  `my_account` ? and since there is no raw contact with `Account name` = `my_account` for those newly added contact details, there is no way of checking the `SOURCE_ID`

Comment: I am really having hard time understanding the Contacts framework and the aggregation.

Comment: @zeekHuge you probably should start a new question. Short answer: a contact app will set your `account_type` and `account_name` when the contact is created in your account. If it doesn't the contact wasn't meant to go into your account (or the app is broken). Or to repharase it a bit: if you have a sync app, your app should not look on contacts which don't have your account type and name. A contact with `account_type == null` is a "local" contact and should not be synced either.